# cx_freeze Won't create Metadata?

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze

When I look at the properties window after building my program, the place where it should give me the version number and description is blank. This is my code

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

exe = Executable(

   script = "ROT13.py",
   initScript = None,
   base = None,
   targetName = "ROT13.exe",
   copyDependentFiles = True,
   compress = True,
   appendScriptToExe = True,
   appendScriptToLibrary = True,
   icon = "blah.png",
)

setup(
    name = "ROT13 Translator",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "A ROT13 Translator",
    executables = [Executable("ROT13.py", base = "Console")]
)
```

Why does this not work?

Comment: How is that properties window generated? What GUI toolkit are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Installing `pywin32` (`pip install pywin32`) solved the issue for me.